# Should I use a dynamic object since my API is returning different property?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find what is the best way to populate a value from an API that only exist once I'm making a second call to it and populating a variable. I wasn't sure if using a dynamic object is the best scenario.

I have the following loop bellow. On my first instance I will get a "pending status" from Postman from my
GetServiceOrderStatusAsync and on my second instance I will get a "success status".

Unfortunately I can't set  "trackingId = serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID" since serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID is only created on a second call.

**This doesn't work:**

```
    var finished = false;
    var trackingId = ""

    do {
       var serviceResults = await client.Services.GetServiceOrderStatusAsync..... 
        
       //This is correct ----1st call
       if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Pending) {
           finished = false;
       }
       // This is not correct because this serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID was never 
       //initialized on the first call.
       if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Success) {
           trackingId = serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID  -> this never exist
           finished = true;
       }
          }
   while (!finished);
```

So I tried this but I'm not sure if it is the best use of dynamic object:

```
        var finished = false;
        var trackingId = "";

        do {
           var serviceResults = await client.Services.GetServiceOrderStatusAsync("11158174", transactionId).ConfigureAwait(false);
            
           if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Pending) {
               finished = false;
           }
           if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Success) {

                dynamic serviceResulys = serviceResults;
                trackingId = serviceResulys.serviceResults.trackingID;  -->will that be the best way?
                finished = true;
           }
           if (serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Error) {
               finished = true;
               transactionId += "Error";
           }
       }
       while (!finished);
```

Here is my Postman call:  first call to the API TrackingID doesn't exist, it only exist when I'm making a second call.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to say since I can't see anything being actually returned in this code. Depending on how you serialize the response, it can be configured to omit nulls

Comment: For the first block of code where it says "This doesn't work", could you explain why exactly it doesn't work? It seems like it'd work fine given how you've explained it. If `serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID` is only populated if the status == Success, and you only access `serviceResults.partnerReference.trackingID` inside an if block for `(serviceResults.Status == ServiceStatus.Success)`, then what's the problem?